# is there any way to solve 'com.apple.product-type.framework' issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow

I am trying to implement cover flow effect in my application by using objectiveFlickr project, But it shows

```
     "target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform"
```

error whenever I am going to be run the application.

Note: I have included all the framework and objectiveflickr library.
      I have made necessary changes in project setting.

There is any solution available for this issues or shall I follow with another sample?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem. Something in my project got messed up as I switched back and forth between Mac targets and iOS targets, causing Xcode to become confused. Reverting the project.pbxproj file inside the xcodeproj package didn't fix the problem. Deleting my entire source tree and updating it from source control *did* fix the problem.

This leads me to believe that the problem lies in the other files inside the xcodeproj package. Try the following:

1. Close your project in Xcode.
2. Navigate into your xcodeproj package (either through Terminal, or in Finder by right-clicking and selecting "Show Package Contents")
3. Delete your pbxuser and perspectivev3 files. They will be re-created.
4. Open your project in Xcode.

Comment: didn't see any of those files attempting this for the iBing client: http://ibing.codeplex.com/

Comment: I also didn't see them using Xcode 4.3. Still, I deleted the user folder inside xcodeproj but it didn't help.

Comment: Same here @Ixx ... I am also not able to see any of the files.And try deleting the user data folder but it didn't helped !!!